# Regularising a Set of Moment Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have seen references to a set of moment equations which are 'regularised' versions of another set of moment equations: could someone clarify what it means to regularise a set of equations in this context?

I know it's nothing to do with regularity theory as that relates to smoothness of weak solutions.